# Como posso retirar um valor do array ao clicar no checkbox em typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um checkbox que ao ser clicado faz um push em um array de nome perm_telas, porém quando seleciono novamente um check já selecionado ele não está removendo corretamente o valor do array.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
  @ViewChildren('myItem') item; //Aqui é meu check
  perm_telas = []; //Aqui é meu array

  OnCheckboxSelect(id, event) { //Caso ocorra um check na tela, adiciona para o array perm_telas o id daquela tela.
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.perm_telas.push(id);
      console.log(this.perm_telas);
    }
    if (event.target.checked === false) {//Caso clique em um já checado, retira aquele id do.
      this.perm_telas = this.perm_telas.filter((item) => id !== id);
    }
  }
```

A inserção está ocorrendo corretamente, acredito que esteja algo errado na minha lógica de retirar do array.

Comment: A condição entra no segundo `if`?

Comment: Sim, o problema está na implementação do remover

Comment: Pedro, isso só funciona quando o array é de objetos. Este código funcionava quando meu array era composto de ({id: id}) porém tive que trocar apenas para um array numérico, então essa função não funciona mais pra mim

Comment: considerando que o `item` é um valor numérico, e `id` também... `this.perm_telas.filter((item) => item !== id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando eu quero remover um determinado item de um objeto eu faço assim:

**Objeto**

```
var array = ['A', 'B', 'F', 1, 2, 3, 5];
```

Procurar **'F'** dentro do objeto. Vai retornar seu índice.

```
var index = array.indexOf('F');
```

Se encontrar o valor, remove.

```
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Onde `index` é a posição e 1 é a quantidade de itens que você quer remover, no caso, um só.

---

No seu caso seria assim:

```
var index = this.perm_telas.indexOf(id);

if (index > -1) {
    this.perm_telas.splice(index, 1);
}
```